# SSISDB logical consistency-based I/O error

Tags: sql-server, ssis

Suddenly my SSISDB got error, the  error message is :

> SQL Server detected a logical consistency-based I/O error: incorrect checksum (expected: 0x7b1871bc; actual: 0x731871bc). It occurred during a read of page (1:156948) in database ID 11 at offset 0x0000004ca28000 in file 'D:\SQL\MSSQL12.PALOMAGROUPBI\MSSQL\DATA\SSISDB.mdf'.  Additional messages in the SQL Server error log or system event log may provide more detail. This is a severe error condition that threatens database integrity and must be corrected immediately. Complete a full database consistency check (DBCC CHECKDB). This error can be caused by many factors; for more information, see SQL Server Books Online. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 824)

I can not open my integration Services Catalog in SSMS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this steps
1.Take a backup of database before any further changes
2.do a DBCC checkdb..this reports which option to use as last resort
3.If your option is repair,then run

> DBCC CHECKDB('DB Name', REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS)

Also MSDN recommends,you to run DBCC checkDB in a transaction to see if the results are acceptable ,which if not can be rolled back..

> Since DBCC CHECKDB with any of the REPAIR options are completely logged and recoverable, Microsoft always recommends a user use CHECKDB with any REPAIR options within a transaction (execute BEGIN TRANSACTION before running the command) so that the user can confirm he/she wants to accept the results of the operation. Then the user can execute COMMIT TRANSACTION to commit all work done by the repair operation. If the user does not want to accept the results of the operation, he/she can execute a ROLLBACK TRANSACTION to undo the effects of the repair operations.

You also can see the page and see what data it holds ...?

in your case page is 1:156948..you can check like below

```
DBCC TRACEON (3604, -1)
GO
DBCC PAGE('YourDatabase', 1, 156948, 3)
```

**References:**
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176064.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Use DBCC to repair, but at the end: BACKUP TIME.

A page on the disc is damaged. Simple as it is. The error is clear on that, you know.

Comment: I've already run DBCC CHECKDB, but no error detected. And I still cannot open the catalog.

CHECKDB found 0 allocation errors and 0 consistency errors in database 'mssqlsystemresource'.
DBCC execution completed. If DBCC printed error messages, contact your system administrator.

Comment: you need to run dbcc checkdb on ssisdb